# Page not redirecting if not exists, just shows code with no data from other page

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

So I have an issue where I'm not being redirected to the 404 if the url doesn't actually exist, instead, it shows code from another page.

So I have a page called *viewpost.php* which typically works only if like *viewpost.php?id=slug-text-of-post*, but if you were to say go to *bloggg.php*, which doesn't exist, it would show you the viewpost page code as if you viewed it without any GET variables. So, the URL will show *bloggg.php*, but show the code from viewpost.php as if nothing would have been passed to it and shows this
[empty page with no data to fill it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDYlV.png)

This below is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ viewcat.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well your .htaccess file is telling the server to redirect everything that is in the address and that doesn't match the previous rules to the page viewpost.php?id=whatever-is-matched maybe you should use `RewriteRule ^viewpost/(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Yes, perfect. Should I do that with the viewcat as well? @TonyMorello

Comment: well it would be good practice to keep a consistent structure, that is not matched by everything like the last row because it has a mandatory `c-` at the beginning but I would use `^cart/(.*)` instead or even better if they are IDs and they are alphanumerical `([0-9]*)`

Comment: What about so the viewcat, shows like `example.com/category/slug-name? that is what I am aiming for

Comment: Same `RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ viewcat.php?id=$1 [QSA, L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achive what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cart/([0-9]*)$ viewcat.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @TonyMorello, appreciate the assistance

Comment: Sure, no problem! ;)